# Spirit Flight between ORD and OAK

Tags: ord, spirit-airlines, oak

Is Spirit planning to cancel their nonstop flight between ORD (O'Hare in Chicago) to OAK (Oakland, CA)?  And, if so, are there any plans to reinstate this route?

I can't seem to be able to find or book flights beyond November 9th for this route.  I tried Googling but I haven't been able to find any news articles or announcements.

Comment: Have you tried calling Spirit?

Comment: I was just hoping someone would know something since their customer service can be a pain, haha.  I'll try calling when I get the chance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [news report](http://centreforaviation.com/analysis/spirit-airlines-feels-sting-of-southwests-discounting-first-signs--emerge-of-changing-network-mix-295346) says that "The routes being cut where Spirit is the only operator are flights from Dallas/Fort Worth and Chicago O’Hare to Oakland." So it appears that Spirit is withdrawing the route.

Comment: In this case, I suggest the OP look for Southwest flights into Midway (MDW) in lieu of O'Hare.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: Or any of the 4 airlines that fly SFO-ORD.  SFO and OAK are closer together than ORD and MDW.

Comment: Sure. Once upon a time Southwest was more likely to have Spirit-level fares, but less so today.

Comment: Thank you @skifans!  And yes, as @Andrew Lazarus suggests, Southwest is not nearly as cheap as they once were.  Their prices are nearly twice as high as Spirit's usually (I don't need any bags other than a backpack).  The SFO-ORD routes can sometimes be comparable to Spirit prices but it's hard to find those sales.  SFO-ORD routes are usually closer to 1.5-2x as expensive as the OAK-ORD Spirit route, so I prefer to take the Spirit route even though SFO is closer to where I need to go.  There's also the hack where you can get $10-14 off each segment with Spirit by booking at the airport.